# Fire the [manager]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

[manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manager) (300+ Questions) is often used together with other tags, like [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file), to form the concept of [file-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-manager).

It is not very useful on its own, and therefore needs clean-up and removal.

Comment: Seems good to me, much too ambiguous.

Comment: Completely agree. On its own the tag is useless, which should be enough to warrant its removal.

Comment: Adding a "me too." I suspect there are a number of these. Not sure if this kind of thing can be easily controlled, though, as folks will just keep generating new partials. Also, when doing social media tagging, folks are trained to separate tags for SEO. That probably spills over into this community.

Comment: This thread is not safe for work. -- Actually manager seems to be (ab)used for all different kinds of managers. Perhaps we would want to retag those questions rather than just removing the tag?

Comment: There are a few instances of this tag used to mean `multiprocessing.Manager` (or subclasses) in python's standard library. These questions should probably be tagged `multiprocessing` and `shared-memory` or `interprocess-communication` (some of them already have these tags).

Comment: just don't change NSFileManger into NSFile

Comment: Managers would disagree. They like to be added to everything, even if it does not make much sense or yield any practical benefit.

Comment: I propose [something-manager](http://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/) instead.

Comment: Suggestion: `fire the [manager]`

Comment: 400 questions now...

Comment: Maybe this question should be retagged with `burnination-request` to fit the current [process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process) (unofficial) and to have an easier time finding it.

Comment: 505 questions now

Comment: Filtered all Android-related and Google Tag Manager questions, 381 left so far

Answer (score 3):

I've retagged all the questions, now we can continue with [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) process.

**Edit**: It is completed.

Comment: Retagging all the questions ***is*** the burnination process. Once you've done that, there is nothing more to do!

Comment: Are you sure? What about users adding new questions with that tag? I've just discussed this request with people in [SOCVR room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and they suggested adding [burninate-request] and flagging for moderator attention

Comment: Absolutely positive. The definition of "burnination" is removing the tag from all questions, so that there are no longer any questions with that tag. Twenty-four hours later, the tag is automatically removed by a process that removes "orphan" tags (those not used on any questions).

Comment: Sound great. Where can I find some more info about that? (like an answer on meta or official docs)

Comment: We don't have any official docs on this. "Burnination" is something invented by the community. There are a slew of Meta questions about it.

Comment: @CodyGray sorry for bugging you, but here is one more question: will users be able to tag new questions with that tag now? Or it should be blacklisted explicitly?

Comment: A new tag can *always* be created, even once it's removed from the system. The way around that is to blacklist it, but blacklisting is only done in rare cases where it is actually necessary (like we've burninated a tag repeatedly and it keeps coming back). There's no reason to think this one will keep coming back. If it does, you'd need to post a new blacklist request. Only developers and community team members can blacklist tags.