# Should [retag-request] be split into [tag-rename-request]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, meta-tags

The current excerpt for the meta-tag [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) is as follows:

> This tag is for requests to replace one tag with another existing tag.
>   It ***also*** applies to requests that one tag should be merged into
>   another, or simply abandoned.

This means that this tag can apply to two separate, distinct types of question:

#### 1) **Retag requests**

Requests to edit questions to replace an misused or obsolete tag with a different, more appropriate tag which already exists. This tag is sometimes used with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

Retags are typically done by users, and is often a lengthy manual process.

- [We have stopped doing [research]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323081/3357935)
- [Fire the [manager]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253081/3357935)
- [Stop inserting [semicolon]s](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317245/3357935)
- [The [dark] side do not join. Lied they did about their cookies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266041/3357935)

#### 2) Tag rename requests

Requests to have an existing tag renamed. This is typically used when a tag's intended use is clear and appropriate, but the tag's name may be incorrect or misleading. This tag is sometimes used with [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request).

Tag renames are typically done by moderators, and is usually a relatively simple process.

- [Rename [atlassian-stash] to [bitbucket-server]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306597/3357935)
- [Rename [osx] to [macos]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348077/3357935)
- [Rename [soundcloud] to [soundcloud-api]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280952/3357935)
- [Proposal to rename "logo" tag to "logo-language"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285335/3357935)

---

[Meta Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/) recently stated separating the second type of question into it's own tag: [**[tag-rename-request]**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-rename-request). I think this would be a good idea for Stack Overflow, and could help clean up some of the confusion around the tag.

**Would there be any objections to creating a new meta tag for [tag-rename-request](/questions/tagged/tag-rename-request)?**

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing as a tag renaming. In all instances I've seen where the name of a tag was "changed" a new tag with the new name was created, then all questions are mass retagged to the new tag, then the old tag is either blacklisted, synonymed, or just left to die.

Comment: @TinyGiant Moderators have a "merge tag" tool that can effectively do this, by simply typing in the old tag name as the "source tag" and then the new tag name as the "destination tag" - it will just rewrite all the questions with the new tag without creating any revisions.

Comment: @animuson That's the mass retagging I was referring to. I should have mentioned that it was done by a moderator tool. The point stands though that the tag is not changed, but replaced with a new tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea and intentions behind a second tag like this are good and sound. I *don't* think separating them will work well for this site in practice.

Arqade is a smaller site with less Meta activity and much fewer retag requests like this. Having separate tags there is unlikely to cause any major problems, and lets moderators easily see requests that they could quickly handle.

Meta Stack Overflow on the other hand has much more activity, and a lot more users regularly visiting. Having two tags for very similar things is going to to lead to a lot of confusion here, and a lot of arguing over which of the two tags is more appropriate for this particular request. Plenty of people will just add both because they assume they're the same thing, or just don't care to look at which one fits better. That's just not something I'd want to introduce to the site here, and sticking to a single tag is probably a better solution.

---

There's also a major difference between the kinds of tags being renamed on Arqade and the kinds of tags being renamed here. A lot of the requests on Arqade are renaming tags to longer versions since the character limit on tags has since changed or minor corrections to the tag name. Those are *very straight-forward* requests that require pretty much no thought to complete.

A lot of the requests here on Stack Overflow are for technologies that have changed their names or maybe weren't specific enough when they were created, which isn't nearly as common a problem for Arqade (games don't tend to change their names once released). These types of requests still require the same amount of attention and discussion from the community before they are processed, to make sure the rename is appropriate. The effectiveness of a separate tag is diminished greatly by this problem.